# Django: How to site wide display queryset result in base template

Tags: django

My django site uses a base template with left, middle and right blocks. The middle and right block are extended by detail templates that get data passed in context by several views.

models.py

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ...

class Code(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    source = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Participant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The left block should always display the results of participant.code_set as a list of code.name as soon as the participant is known.

I previously did this by adding the pickled participant instance in the session as soon as it was known and then looping over session.participant.code_set in the base template.

Is there an other way to achieve the same without using the PickleSerializer for sessions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution: Context Processor

context_processor.py

```
def inject_codes(request):
    try:
        codes = Code.objects.filter(author=request.session['participant']['pk'])
        return {'codes': codes}
    except KeyError:
        return {}
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...,
                'draw.context_processor.inject_codes',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```